# Anchor Links from One Page to Another in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a real estate site that dynamically populates the /listings page with a list of all current listings in the database - and, I have a sidebar on the other pages that randomly displays one listing at a time if it is tagged as 'featured'.  Since the sidebar is just a summary of the listing, I would like to provide a link that would take the visitor to the /listing list page and then based on the anchor, position the screen to the featured listing they would like to see. I can get the anchor to work if I hard code a link outside of the object loop for the listings, but can get it to work dynamically using the id of the listing.

**Here is what I am attempting to do:**

**My Sidebar** - *Notice the 'More Info' link before the closing  - I would like to use the unique object ID as the anchor link*

```
{% for listing in listings %}
  <div class="featured-block">
    ...
    <p style="font-weight: bold">For more information please contact {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }} at {{ listing.phone }}.<a href="{% url 'listing_list' %}#{{ listing.id }}">More Info</a></p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I then have an `<a name="{{ listing.id }}"></a>` on the listing page; I even tried `<div id="{{ listing.id }}"></div>` with no luck.

Is it because the link from the sidebar is linking to an anchor on the listings page that hasn't been generated yet?  Any help is always greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
{% for listing in listings %}
  <div class="featured-block">
    ...
    <p style="font-weight: bold">For more information please contact {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }} at {{ listing.phone }}.<a href="{% url 'listing_list' listing.id %}">{{listing.id}}</a></p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The url template tag

```
{% url 'listing_list' listing.id %}
```

will generate the url for the id refer [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url) and

```
{{listing.id}}
```

will show the id on the html

Comment: Thanks.  I am getting a 'NoReverseMatch' error, which according to the link you provided is expected at times.  I am still a bit of a noob at this and can't figure out how to use the docs to format my link to get rid of the 'NoReverseMatch' - can you lend a hand on this?  Thank you.

Comment: it would be related to the urls issue... can you provide the url you added in url.py

Comment: url(r'^$', listing_list, name='listing_list')

Comment: as per the url config it doesn't seems that you are redirecting to any of the page.... If you want url to be the same for each item in list then you can change {% url 'listing_list' listing.id %} to {% url 'listing_list' %}.... otherwise you would have to make the url to have some unique id and use that in the urls....

Comment: just go through the polls tutorial and it would be easier for you to understand... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/.... most probabaly you can skip tutorial01 &  tutorial02 pages as per your understanding.... just a 5 page tutorial would take hardly 30 minutes :)

Comment: Thank you.  I'll look into it and then report back my solution for the benefit of others.